# Why won't bundle install my local gem w/ extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, native

I have a gem I'm developing locally with the following structure:

```
foo
  ext
   foo
    extconf.rb
    foo.cpp
    foo.h
    etc.cpp
    etc.h
  lib
 foo.gemspec
```

--- foo.gemspec --

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name    = "foo"
  s.version = "0.0.2"
  s.author  = "Aemon Cannon"
  s.files = Dir["ext/foo/*.{h,cpp}"] + Dir["lib/**/*"] + Dir['ext/**/extconf.rb']
  s.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.require_paths = [ 'lib', 'ext' ]
  s.extensions = Dir['ext/**/extconf.rb']
end
```

--- ext/foo/extconf.rb ----

```
require 'mkmf'
$CPPFLAGS += "-std=c++11 -Wno-unused-value "
abort "missing libz" unless  have_library("z")
abort "missing c++ standard library" unless have_library("stdc++")
create_makefile "foo"
```

I use gem build foo to build a gem, which seems to build successfully, then add the gem to my rails app under vendor/gems. I mention it in my Gemfile thusly:

```
gem 'foo', '0.0.2', :path => 'vendor/gems'
```

When I 'bundle install' it says:

```
Using foo (0.0.2) from source at vendor/gems
```

BUT it does not appear to build the extension, and now the gem has been deleted from vendor/gems and does not appear in vendor/cache.

'gem install foo-0.0.1.gem' installs the gem properly, building the native extension successfully.

Rails version 3.2.x
Bundler 1.5.x

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I guess that bunlder does not run the `gem` command to install gem that is specified with `path` key. How to force installation I dont know, may be to write a rake rule to automatically build a gem then install it: like `rake install`, whic will run `bundle install`, then build the specific gem, and install it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Bundler docs for using `:path`](http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/gemfile.5.html#PATH-path-) say:

> Unlike **:git**, bundler does not compile C extensions for gems specified as paths.

My understanding is that `:path` is mainly intended for using with gems that you are actively developing, and Bundler expects “ready to go” code at that location. If you want to use `:path`, you should compile the extension manually first (perhaps using [rake-compiler](https://github.com/luislavena/rake-compiler)).

Comment: Thanks. So what would you recommend if I want to ship a gem+extension with my Rails app? Development happens on mac/windows, deploys to heroku, so pre-building the extension sounds a pain.

Comment: This is still true of the as of [v2.3](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/gemfile.5.html#PATH).